# Redimensionar imagem para tamanho da tela

Tags: java, android, imagem

criei uma classe ViewA onde pego duas imagens da pasta drawable e desenho na tela com o metodo draw();

```
public class ViewA extends View {

private Bitmap img1;
private Bitmap img2;

public ViewA(Context context){
    super(context);
    img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagem01);
    img2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagem02);
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(img1, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(img2, 0, 0, null);
}
```

}

e aqui está a MainActtivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewA view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = new ViewA(this);
    setContentView(view);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

}
```

}

está full screen porém na hora de pegar as imagens e a desenhar na tela, supondo que seja uma imagem de resolução 1920x1080 as imagens fica cortada e só aparece uma parte da imagem.
Queria saber se tem como colocar essas imagens inteira na tela !! sem que fique cortada.

Comment: ` img1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img1, 1300, 800, true);` eu achei essa solução, porem se mudar de dispositivo não preenche a tela toda ...

Answer (score 1):

Se a ideia for colocar uma imagem de fundo na activity faça o seguinte:

sua_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:scaleType= "fitCenter"          <- escolha aqui o tipo de ajuste
        android:src="@drawable/imagem"/>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...         <- controles que vão sobrepor a imagem de fundo

     </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Veja a documentação dos tipos de ajuste em [ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Caso queira ter um mais controle sobre a imagem, crie uma classe derivada da *ImageView*

Comment: então no caso a imagem ja coloquei pelo médodo draw(); o problema é que se for uma imagem pequena ela não preenche a tela toda e se for grande fica cortada. eu não usei uma imageview na activity

Comment: Seria mais fácil no layout da activity. Mas faça o seguinte: derive _NomeClass_ de _ImageView_ e não da _View_ e não sobreponha o método _onDraw_. A partir daí é só usar os métodos que a _ImageView_ oferece como por exemplo _setScaleType_

Comment: Para setar a imagem use _setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem)_ não precisa decodificar para _Bitmap_

Comment: o scaleType não ajusta a imagem para ocupar a tela toda. Eu tentei usar na activity e não preencheu fica uma borda ainda !  Obs: o aplicativo esta full screen

Comment: Edite a pergunta, adicione o código fonte e detalhe a forma que esta tentado fazer.