# Ajustar imagem automaticamente em vários tipos de dispositivo

Tags: android, imagem

Eae blz ?! Então estou tentando trabalhar com imagens em classes nativas android, onde a imagem é exibida por meio de uma classe !!
já tenho uma pergunta onde o link esttá logo abaixo !!

[Redimensionar imagem para tamanho da tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165079/redimensionar-imagem-para-tamanho-da-tela)

Até agora não achei nada sobre, e estou pensando em criar varias classes que seria uma para cada tipo de tela e na mainactivity tratava isso ae mas naum sei como fuinciona o esquema das telas e as funções.
Será que tem algum material de estudo ou tutorial para isso??

Comment: algum motivo especial para não usar bibliotecas como o Glide ou o Picasso?

Comment: Não seria mais fácil adicionar uma imageview no XML?

Comment: Mr_Anderson vou dar uma olhada nas biblioteca, e Rafael Silva o problema é que o aplicativo está full screen e uma imagem até ocupa a tela toda porém a sgunda imagem que eu quero sobrepor eu não consegui ocupar a tela toda

Comment: Eu acho desnecessário...o Glide é muito simples de usar...é só digitar:
Glide.with(context).load(myImg).into(imageView);
onde context é o contexto, myImg é a própria imagem, que pode ser qualquer formato, e a imageView é o widget já instanciado.

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide